# What is the colon in the c language between two strings?

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to edit the IDT (interrupt Descriptor Table) and I have found [this code](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples#LIDT) which should give me access to the structure. But I didn't understand what the colon in the `asm` line is. I guess that it's some game with bitmaps in C, and this is somehow padding the instruction. But I couldn't find anything definitive.

If it helps, right now the compiler says: `invalid 'asm': invalid expression as operand`. Still fighting this one... :)

So, what is the colon doing there?

Comment: "the compiler": Are you using gcc? (That's what these examples are written for. Just about every compiler has its own version of inline assembly.)

Comment: @Jongware: indeed, this question is not about the C language at all.

Comment: I'm using `gcc 4.7.3`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck feel free to retag the question. I admit not knowing how it should be tagged.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the extended asm syntax from `gcc` compiler. Here's a [link](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#toc5) describing the syntax:

```
   asm ( assembler template 
       : output operands                  /* optional */
       : input operands                   /* optional */
       : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
       );
```

and the example:

```
    int a=10, b;
    asm ("movl %1, %%eax; 
          movl %%eax, %0;"
         :"=r"(b)        /* output */
         :"r"(a)         /* input */
         :"%eax"         /* clobbered register */
         );
```

> - "b" is the output operand, referred to by %0 and "a" is the input
>     operand, referred to by %1.
> - "r" is a constraint on the operands. We’ll
>     see constraints in detail later. For the time being, "r" says to GCC
>     to use any register for storing the operands. output operand
>     constraint should have a constraint modifier "=". And this modifier
>     says that it is the output operand and is write-only.
> - There are two
>     %’s prefixed to the register name. This helps GCC to distinguish
>     between the operands and registers. operands have a single % as
>     prefix.
> - The clobbered register %eax after the third colon tells GCC
>     that the value of %eax is to be modified inside "asm", so GCC won’t
>     use this register to store any other value.